# How can I get all the users that has commented a post?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I've the following Models

PostComment.php

```
class PostComment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_group_id', 'user_id', 'comment_content'
    ];

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PostGroup');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

PostGroup.php

```
class PostGroup extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id', 'user_id', 'post_content'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }

    public function commented(){
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\PostComment'
        );
    }
}
```

Group.php

```
class Group extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ([
    'id'
    ]);

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\User',
            'user_group'
        );
    }

    public function members(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           'App\User',
           'user_group'
        )->wherePivot('state','accepted');
    }


    public function posted(){
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\PostGroup'
        );
    }
}
```

My web application presents `groups`, in which you can create `posts` and in which post you can write `comments`. In my database I've the following relationships:

- Group: (id, name, description);
- PostGroup: (id, group_id, user_id, post_content);
- PostComment: (id, post_group_id, user_id, comment_content);

**What I want to do is** to create a collection of User objects, and then make a query **to get all users, subscribed to a group, who have commented on a certain post**, in MySQL looks like:

```
select users.* from users, post_comments where users.id = post_comments.user_id and post_comments.post_group_id="1"
```

So in my controller I've the following code

```
$theGroup = Group::find($groupId);
$thePost = PostGroup::find($postId);
$memberList = User::where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('id', $theGroup->users->pluck('id'))->
```

So, what I want to do is to extend that query to get the desidered result with `->get()->sortBy('last_name');`, how can I exted it after the `whereIn`?

**EDIT**

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','created_at','updated_at'
    ];

    public function groups(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','user_group');
    }

    public function groupsAsAdmin(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','user_group')->wherePivot('role','admin');
    }

    public function groupsAsMember(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','user_group')->wherePivot('state','accepted');
    }

    public function groupsAsInvited(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','user_group')->wherePivot('state','pending');
    }

    public function posted(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostGroup');
    }

    public function commented(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostComment');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that a user has commented on a post (which means he was part of the group the post was written in), but is not part of the group anymore? If yes, does the user should show up in the result for the post or not?

Comment: No, because in the first part of the query `User::where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('id', $theGroup->users->pluck('id'))` I get all the users in a group, so there's no problem to think about it because the user it's excluded from the group, and for me it's ok. I hope it's clear.

Comment: I always need **users subscribed to the group**, but only who have commented on a certain post, this because I'm going to create a notification system, and that's only for the members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you already come up with a list of `Users` in advance, so that you only will find `Posts` with a `Comment` of these specific users.

Basically, what you want is to use `whereHas($relation, $calback)` to perform the checks you described:

```
$userIds = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]; // or query them...
$postId = 123; // the id of the post where we want to look through the comments

User::where('id', '<>', Auth::id())
    ->whereIn('id', $userIds)
    ->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($postId) {
        $query->where('post_group_id', $postId);
    })
    ->get();
```

This will simply check if a user has written a `Comment` for the given post. Because you forgot to post your `User` model, I assumed that there is a relation available for the `comments` of the user.

You could also combine the first two conditions (user in list, but not the authenticated one) into one, if you want. `$userIds = array_diff($userId, [Auth::id()])` does the job. `where('id', '<>', Auth::id())` can be dropped from the query then.

If you do also need to check for an active subscription of the user to a group, it will be slightly more complex. But as you commented, you are already finding only users for a group, so this should be fine.

Comment: As I said, the list of users is the following: `$memberList = User::where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('id', $theGroup->users->pluck('id'))->get();`, that query gives to me all the members in a group and I need to process my query only on this list of users, I'll try your solution and let you know.

Comment: If you need I posted the user model.

Comment: I get `local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments() `

Comment: Swap `whereHas('comments'` for `whereHas('commented'` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In PostComment, try this

```
$this->selectRaw(‘user_id, comment_content’)->where(‘post_group_id’, 1)->groupBy(‘user_id’)->get();
```